# getting promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I am new to react-native.

I want to send multiple values to the server by API body.
So I store IT in Async and Then Get by getItems. but when I send multiple items it's giving an error like this == promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<' otherwise for a single value it's working fine. but I have sent multiple value

Here is my code

```
AsyncStorage.multiGet(['application_id', 'created_by'], (application_id, first_name) => {
    fetch('https://nasdigital.tech/Android_API_CI/uploaddata/tbl_nsdgtl_merchant_retail_details', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        // We convert the React state to JSON and send it as the POST body
        body: JSON.stringify([{created_by:first_name, application_id:application_id }])
    })
    .then((returnValue) => returnValue.json())
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
    });
});
```

Comment: can I've sample parameters and baseURL pls, we need to call fetch, correct?

Comment: I want to send user name and application id. so just tell me How acually multiGet works

Comment: yes thats url i want to send username and id

Comment: please tell me How to do that with multiGet

Comment: It's like you want to call the API by passing post parameters, correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: I want to send username and id to server with form data. I want to send that this username and this ID has send this form

Comment: form data is used to upload images/videos, I'm not sure why do you want to send with form data

Comment: just tell me how to use multiGet or how to get multiple itme wwith async

Comment: are you sure that API is working? it's not working on postman also

Comment: just tell me how to use multiGet or how to get multiple itme wwith async